# Transition to scaling out with signalr and redis from signalr and sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, redis, signalr

I am currently testing signalr with sql server as my backplane. If I switch sql with redis, how would I be able to incorporate sql database in that design via programming not set up.

For example My stored procedure saves user profile properties like (height, interests), now when i need to grab that information into an object along with data in redis(how many likes a photo has within that user profile by providing the user profile as a key).

I initially had sql server doing the work where I edit the number of likes on the table and bam, it pops up automatically with signalr like it supposed to.

Now because of performance reasons I would like the same results, except having redis storing the likes of the user profile, and sql persisting the rest of the user profile object.

Sorry if I confused anyone, let me know and I will re-edit immediately.

Comment: Is this _programming_ or _server management_? If it's the latter, you'd be better served over at [Server Fault.SE](http://serverfault.com/). If it's the former, please clarify how this is a programming question, so future visitors don't get confused. Of course, it could well be obvious to someone who knows what all those words mean, so feel free to ignore me if that's the case.

Comment: No need to ignore anyone lol we're all friends here. Its more toward a programming question than a server management one. For example I have a sql server DB persisting user profile information. But I would also like to use redis as my backplane for signalr scaleout. So how does one go by saving to the db and also using redis at the same time. I have a stored procedure saying save to userprofile (values), now if user profile gets a like on their photo. Id like that to be distributed by a redis backplane. I am just lost on how combining the two for my app would work.

Comment: Well, I'm personally getting confused because I don't see a reference to any... well, any programming, just how to use two (usually server-based) technologies. Could you clarify more how it's a programming question (preferably in your question)? (Also, it's typically frowned upon to ask for links to diagrams -- just ask your question, and if links or diagrams come in handy in the answer, we'll provide them)

Comment: The diagram was an optional suggestion, it wasn't a request. Since you corrected how the community might view it, I won't ask it anymore. Thank you for that. You're right, and honestly I am confusing myself. I am currently testing signalr with sql server as my backplane. If I switch sql with redis, how would I be able to incorporate sql database in that design via programming not set up. For example My stored procedure saves user profile properties like (height, interests), now when i need to grab that information into an object along with data in redis, is where I am confused.

Comment: Much better! Now, click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30429911/edit) (or the link below your question that says 'edit') and put that in your question, so doofuses (doofi?) like me don't get confused.

Comment: You're not the doof, too much stress and no sleep AND game of thrones on tonight, is incapacitating my abilities to stack-overflow and type.